# Sunlight layer into CartoDB

Tags: carto, layers, cartocss, twitter

I have a list of tweets on a torque map made with CartoDB. I want to add an additional layer that shows the sunlight around the world at certain times, similar to the Twitter #sunrise map found [here](http://cartodb.s3.amazonaws.com/static_vizz/sunrise.html?title=true&description=true&search=false&shareable=true&cartodb_logo=true&layer_selector=false&legends=false&scrollwheel=true&sublayer_options=1%7C1&sql=&zoom=2&center_lat=22.917922936146045&center_lon=51.328125#).

Does anyone know how to add a layer like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Leaflet plugin you can implement in any CartoDB map, you can find it here: https://github.com/joergdietrich/Leaflet.Terminator