# Sunlight based on GPS coordinates and UTC+date

Tags: gps

I'm trying to create a sunlight map. I found the following question: [Sunlight layer into CartoDB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108161/sunlight-layer-into-cartodb)

However, my interest is in trying to calculate the amount of sunlight manually. Can you please point me to the formulas/documentation on how I could compute the amount of sunlight (sunrise/sunset) based on GPS coordinates and UTC/date?

Comment: Could you please clarify "amount" of sunlight? Do you only need to know the duration of daylight (sunrise to sunset) or also its intensity?

Comment: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/

Comment: @StephenLead: just the duration is fine... basically theoretically, without knowing clouds/weather, which hours of the day would be 'sunny'.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is strictly a GIS question..... I just googled "sunrise calculation" and got some promising hits, including [How to calculate sunrise and set](https://maas.museum/observations/2007/10/30/how-to-calculate-sunrise-and-set-a-worked-example/) and [sunrise equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pyephem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) Python module can help here. From the [docs](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/rise-set.html):

```
>>> import ephem
>>> atlanta = ephem.Observer()
>>> atlanta.pressure = 0
>>> atlanta.horizon = '-0:34'
>>> atlanta.lat, atlanta.lon = '33.8', '-84.4'
>>> atlanta.date = '2009/09/06 17:00' # noon EST
>>> print(atlanta.previous_rising(ephem.Sun()))
2009/9/6 11:14:57
>>> print(atlanta.next_setting(ephem.Sun()))
2009/9/6 23:56:10
```

Note that the above times are UTC.

Comment: Thank you for this. I know I will need to read the docs carefully, but could you say whether the pressure and horizon settings are very important? I'm trying to calculate a sunlight map and I don't have pressure/horizon for all points on the map... Should I just set them both to zero?

Comment: @econ Dunno on the pressure and horizon settings, I'm not an astronomer by any stretch, just have used pyephem before. I'd read the docs and do some further research on how those parameters relate to sunrise and sunset.